# Merge axes before and after the i^{th} axis

Tags: python, numpy

I want to reshape a numpy array `arr` to a shape of `(before, at, after)` for any one `axis` of `arr`. How to do this faster?

The axis has been normalized: `0 <= axis < arr.ndim`

Program:

```
import numpy as np
def f(arr, axis):
    shape = arr.shape
    before = int(np.product(shape[:axis]))
    at = shape[axis]
    return arr.reshape(before, at, -1)
```

Test:

```
a = np.arange(2 * 3 * 4 * 5).reshape(2, 3, 4, 5)
print(f(a, 2).shape)
```

Result:

```
(6, 4, 5)
```

Comment: % timeit (f(a, 2).shape)
8.14 µs ± 489 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)  Are you really interested in speed? ;)

Comment: It is Friday night and I guess I am bored or OCD lol.  Things like `arr += np.arange(arr.size, dtype=arr.dtype)` is a bit crazy in the same sense but many people do that. It is just a simple loop in c++ ...

Comment: using reduceat from below   5.08 µs ± 234 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)   so you will have more time on your hands ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shape` is a tuple, and the desired result is also a tuple.  Convert to/from arrays to use `np.prod` or some other array function will take time.  So if we can do the same with plain Python code we might save time.

For example with `shape`:

```
In [309]: shape
Out[309]: (2, 3, 4, 5)
In [310]: np.prod(shape)
Out[310]: 120
In [311]: functools.reduce(operator.mul,shape)
Out[311]: 120

In [312]: timeit np.prod(shape)
13.6 µs ± 30.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [313]: timeit functools.reduce(operator.mul,shape)
647 ns ± 12.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The python version is noticeably faster.  I had to import `functools` and `operator` to get the multiplication equivalent of `sum` (Python3).

Or to get the new shape tuple:

```
In [314]: axis=2
In [315]: (functools.reduce(operator.mul,shape[:axis]),shape[axis],-1)
Out[315]: (6, 4, -1)
In [316]: timeit (functools.reduce(operator.mul,shape[:axis]),shape[axis],-1)
739 ns ± 30.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

comparing the proposed `reduceat`:

```
In [318]: tuple(np.multiply.reduceat(shape, (0, axis, axis+1)))
Out[318]: (6, 4, 5)
In [319]: timeit tuple(np.multiply.reduceat(shape, (0, axis, axis+1)))
11.3 µs ± 21.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: with initializer, it can work with axis=0. `(functools.reduce(operator.mul,shape[:axis], 1),shape[axis],-1)`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33945882/reduce-function-doesnt-handle-an-empty-list

Comment: @hpaulj I might even use that ;-)

Comment: @hamsteronwheels still inserts an awkward 1 on the left. OTOH, that may even be desirable in some cases

Answer (score 1):

If your axis is really in the middle you can use `np.multiply.reduceat`

```
 shape = (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
 axis = 2
 np.multiply.reduceat(shape, (0, axis, axis+1))
 # array([ 6,  4, 30])
 axis = 3
 np.multiply.reduceat(shape, (0, axis, axis+1))
 # array([24,  5,  6])
```

If you want the zeroth or last axis you'll have to special case, though.